# How to determine package name of app which throws exception in logcat?

Tags: android, logcat

Recently I encountered a problem on my phone. I look into logcat almost every day and few days ago I've noticed that logcat is flooded with one exception. Exactly this one:

```
2019-05-26 11:23:19.034 14375-14441/? W/Bundle: Key android.icon expected Parcelable but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value <null> was returned.
2019-05-26 11:23:19.034 14375-14441/? W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
        at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:946)
        at android.app.Notification.fixDuplicateExtra(Notification.java:2840)
        at android.app.Notification.fixDuplicateExtras(Notification.java:2830)
        at android.app.Notification.readFromParcelImpl(Notification.java:2178)
        at android.app.Notification.<init>(Notification.java:2106)
        at android.app.Notification$1.createFromParcel(Notification.java:2716)
        at android.app.Notification$1.createFromParcel(Notification.java:2713)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2790)
        at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent.readAccessibilityRecordFromParcel(AccessibilityEvent.java:1232)
        at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent.initFromParcel(AccessibilityEvent.java:1182)
        at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent$1.createFromParcel(AccessibilityEvent.java:1426)
        at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent$1.createFromParcel(AccessibilityEvent.java:1423)
        at android.accessibilityservice.IAccessibilityServiceClient$Stub.onTransact(IAccessibilityServiceClient.java:68)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)
```

I also noticed that my battery started to drain much faster probably because of that. Actually Google Play Services are quite high on the battery info list when I look on 1 week history

How can I determine which app is writing this exception? Is it actually possible? Maybe you have other ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the problem - is your phone crashing? The crash dialog should tell you which app caused the crash

Comment: Nope phone is not crashing. Only increased battery drain.